# Codeigniter: How can I prevent changing the website style?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I am able to run the website properly on localhost, however when I uploaded to the live server, and fill the form and insert the value in one of the specific textbox ( promo code) , my website style changes and messes the whole look. I cannot select or send the form and have to refresh the page. This was not doing on the localhost, it is only doing on live site. Can you please advice?

I have attached the screenshot for you to understand what it does actually.

Thanks in advance.

***(when i insert the value in the textbox)***
[image]

***(when i loose focus from the textbox)***
[image]

***(And in the localhost)***
[image]

Comment: Bring the console outputs of devtool of browser, may be stylesheets reference path issue..

Comment: @JenuJ , i tried looking the CSS in the console of the browser but not able to understand it.

Comment: Did you change the baseurl in ur live instance?

Comment: no, I didnt change anything

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492070/css-wont-trigger-in-live-production-with-codeigniter-framework/53492147#53492147

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS wont trigger in live production with CodeIgniter framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492070/css-wont-trigger-in-live-production-with-codeigniter-framework)